# SSH_AUTH_SOCK set to wrong value after login but there is nothing that sets it explicitly

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, kde, environment-variables, ssh-agent

I am using KDE on Arch Linux and I am trying to run gpg-agent in ssh-agent emulation mode as described [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GnuPG#SSH_agent).

I created env file `~/.config/environment.d/80_gpg_agent.conf` for [systemd-environmentd-generator](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/30-systemd-environment-d-generator.8.html):

```
PINENTRY=pinentry-qt
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh
```

I do not set `SSH_AGENT_PID` because it is not accepted by mentioned generator but it shouldn't be set anyway (and it isn't).

If I start my system and login into TTY I am getting correct value for `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` (from `systemctl --user show-environment`):
Then, if I don't login into KDE session I have correct value for SSH_AUTH_SOCK:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh
```

After I log into KDE session (doesn't matter if it is Wayland or X11) I see that this value of overwritten by something:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/ssh-agent.socket
```

This value looks like standard value usually set for [ssh-agent](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SSH_keys#ssh-agent) but I don't have unit files for ssh-agent autostart.

So far I checked the following:

- there is no code that sets `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` in `.bashrc`, `.profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `/etc/profile` or `/etc/profile.d/*`
- there are no env variables in `/etc/environment` or `~/.config/environment.d/*` besides one that I set for gpg-agent
- I use keepassxc that has embedded ssh-agent but I didn't add it to autostart and its ssh-agent disabled

So, question is, where is it set and how do I stop this from overriding my env?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like issue was due to use of (deprecated) `~/.pam_environment` of `pam_env` module.

I found out that ~/.pam_environment has override for `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/ssh-agent.socket`

Since it is marked as deprecated I didn't even thought it might be used.